# Explaining password regex component by component (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

`/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8}/`

This RegEx is supposed to validate a password, which should contain at least one digit, both lowercase and uppercase characters. Can anyone explain this RegEx by smaller components?

Comment: Ask questions about regular expressions, not about _your_ regular expression.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to be fair, its just an example. Like most examples, the knowledge is assumed to be applicable to other scenarios.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
/(?=.\d)(?=.[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8}/
```

This regex is generally used to validate password, i.e.

password should contain `1 UpperCase`,`1 LowerCase` and `1 numeric` and `no special characters`.

```
(?=.*\d) //at least 1 numeric charater.

(?=.*[a-z]) //atleast 1 lowercase.

(?=.*[A-Z]) //atleast 1 uppercase.

.{6,8} //string is of 6 to 8 length.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

`(?=.*\d)` ensures your string has a digit in it.

`(?=.*[a-z])`ensures your string has a lowercase ASCII letter in it.

`(?=.*[A-Z])`ensures your string has a uppercase ASCII letter in it.

`.{6,8}` matches a string of atleast 6 and atmost 8 characters.

Since the anchors are missing, your regex would match any string which has as its substring a string that satisfies all of the above 4 conditions.

Comment: (and of course, again, it's only ASCII letters and digits. Also, without anchors, strings that are longer than 8 characters will also (partially) match)...

Comment: +1 and deleted mine, because you typed faster.

Answer (score 6):

`(?=..)` means: Let the string after the current position contain `..`.

```
(?=.*\d)    # Somewhere, at least one digit should appear
(?=.*[a-z]) #            and at least a lowercase letter
(?=.*[A-Z]) #            and at least an uppercase letter
.{6,8}      #            must consist of 6-8 characters
```

Your pattern is missing the markers for the beginning and the end of a string. Add `^` and `$`:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8}$/
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 ?= is look ahead for the following feature within brackets ()
 then (?=.*\d) 0 or more of any character that is a decimal 0-9
 then (?=.*[a-z]) after that look ahead for 0 or more a-z characters 
 then (?=.*[A-Z]) after that look ahead for 0 or more A-Z uppercase characters 
 .{6,8}/ and then must be 6-8 character long
```

without the beginning ^ or ending $ this will match any string of 6-8 characters matching the above rules.

if you change the * to + then it will match 1 or more characters

Answer (score 3):

Look at different parts,

`(?=.*\d)` password must be at least 6 characters, and at most 8 letters long..

`^(?=.*\d)` contains one number,

`(?=.*[a-z])` one small alphabet and

`(?=.*[A-Z])` one capital letter..

You can use like this

```
 ^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{lower_limit, upper_limit}$
```

for at least one small letter, one capital letter, and one number with any restriction of length(lower, upper)

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression is ambiguous.  You should not use the combination of characters ".*".  The period means any character and the asterisk many 0 or more occurrences, which is likely the entirety of your string.